# Is it appropriate to share tips that we have learned that might benifit others?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it would it be appropriate at times to ask and then answer your own questions as a means to share tips that you have learned that might benefit others? Or if this would just end up just wasting people's time, and should be discouraged? Considering the system does not allow you to mark your own answer during the first 2 days, this obviously might be of concern.

I would assume of course that people would need to use restraint and good judgement (i.e. only share tips that are useful and broadly applicable, not easily discovered by reading the documentation or from other questions, provide a specific use case, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely! Here are a few examples...

- [What’s the recommended way to set the site URL?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/920/45)
- [How can I output a timeframe in fully written notation nicely?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/155/45)
- [Is there a way I can programmatically download the latest version of Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/225/45)

It's true that you can't accept your own answer for two days. However, you *can* "Answer your own question" at the same time as you are posting your question. The delay is simply there to prevent you from **assuming** your answer is the best... maybe someone else has a better suggestion.

The focus of Stack Exchange is to "bring solutions to the community"... as long as you're doing that, I don't think anyone will complain.

Answer (score 4):

I personally think this is 100% acceptable.  The purpose of this site is to archive knowledge so this is a good fit.

When you're posting a question, there is a checkbox that asks you if you want to answer your own question. Click that and an answer field will be displayed for you to complete.

Comment: Beat me to it. :)